# Are there any C# wrappers for the Bitcoin REST API?

Tags: development, api

Are there any C# wappers that take an OOO approach to the Bitcoin REST API, and encapsulate it in an easy to use format?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this c# bitcoin rpc api wrapper: https://github.com/GeorgeKimionis/BitcoinLib that, unlike bitnet, is up-to-date.

Comment: This is so far the best library on this page!

Answer (score 2):

The newest up to date c# library for .net  is [.Net-Bitcoin-RPC](https://github.com/edmlbox/.Net-Bitcoin-RPC) with full documentation about each call. Very easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of [WalletClient.net](https://github.com/chriswill/WalletClient) and it's fairly up to date, covering most of the json-rpc commands.  It has an async model and strongly typed return objects. There's also specific support for Blockchain.info vs native Bitcoind.

Let me know what you think.

Comment: I like the Blockchain integration, George's solution seems to be better on the QT side.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote my own wrapper,
it wasn't complicated, 
this is the basic gist of it below. 
Adapt for your specific needs.

**Example of getting raw transaction**

```
internal static string GetRawTransaction(string txid)
{
    var CredentialCache = new CredentialCache();
    CredentialCache.Add(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:8332"), "Basic", new NetworkCredential("[your rpc username]", "your rpc password"));

    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://127.0.0.1:8332");
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
    httpWebRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache;

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        string json;
        json = "{ \"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\", \"id\":\"" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "\", \"method\": \"getrawtransaction\",\"params\":[\"" + txid + "\",1]}";

        streamWriter.Write(json);
    }
    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        return responseText;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Glasswalker/Wallet.Net/tree/master/Bitnet.Client
I use bitnet client, nothing but good things to say, if its missing anything you need its quite easy to add/modify anything you need.

If you open up bitcoin -qt then go to the console and type in help you will see a list of all the methods. (as not every single one is implemented in bitnet)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my job, mostly for transactions but probably I'll update it in free time

https://github.com/kamilk91/BitcoinManagerCsharp