# Manually creating transactions

Tags: development, bitcoind, json-rpc

Due to complete lack of documentation on the subject, how would the pseucode for creating a transaction look using the following functions: `createrawtransaction` `signrawtransaction` and `sendrawtransaction`.

I receive the user transaction for incoming coins on IncomingTxID, when I create a raw transction I want to include at least some of those coins so if they won't confirm, neither will his payout.

Comment: Related: [C# API for Bitcoin](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/5461/1878)

Comment: How to do this is documented in [_Mastering Bitcoin_ (1st ed.), §"Using Bitcoin Core’s JSON-RPC API from the Command Line"](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001802/ch03.html#_using_bitcoin_core_8217_s_json_rpc_api_from_the_command_line), §§"Creating, Signing, and Submitting Transactions Based on Unspent Outputs".

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you want to accomplish something akin to what SatoshiDice does. Here is how it can be done, using API calls with the Bitcoin-Qt/bitcoind client:

1. `listunspent` - you get the list of all unspent transactions
2. You determine which ones you want to spend
3. You use `createrawtransaction` to create your inputs / outputs, taking `txid` and `vout` from the list of transactions that you have that are playing, as well as a list of transactions that constitute a "money supply" for you.
4. Use `signrawtransaction` to sign the created transaction
5. Use `sendrawtransaction` to send the signed transaction

That should be pretty much it. I have implemented some of that code myself and it is pretty easy once you get a hang of it all.

Comment: One bit of caution -- in the raw transaction, any inputs used that are not fully spent go to the miner.  So be very careful when composing raw transactions.

Comment: How about fee calculation?

Comment: @Shamoon http://bitcoinfees.com/ - you base them on the number of inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 2):

A good way to see this (and also a non-automated method to do this) is available through BrainWallet:

- http://brainwallet.org/#tx

Comment: One bit of caution -- in the raw transaction, any inputs used that are not fully spent go to the miner.  So be very careful when composing raw transactions.