# How to implement cold storage payments using bitcoind

Tags: bitcoind, coldstorage

I wonder what APIs of bitcoind I can use to sign a transaction without actually publishing it. I read that createrawtransaction (in conjunction with signrawtransaction) is a bit risky and for sure poorly documented. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manually creating transactions](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5508/manually-creating-transactions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Using bitcoind](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5508), sendrawtransaction is one of the steps normally performed.  So to not broadcast, simply omit that command.

For an alternative, you might want to look at SX>

SX is a set of modular Bitcoin commandline utilities that admin types can engage with Bitcoin functionality without having to write code.

- http://sx.dyne.org
- http://bitcoinmagazine.com/6234/what-libbitcoin-and-sx-are-and-why-they-matter/

Using the Mycelium mobile app has to be the easiest method to spend funds from a paper wallet. From the app, select Cold Storage. Then scan the private key from the wallet. Then scan the QR code for the Bitcoin address to send the funds to.